# \end{comment} in \newcommand

Tags: macros, comments

I want to define a new command containing \end{comment} (I need it for some conditional compiling). If I do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand{\myendcomment}{\end{comment}}

\begin{document}

\begin{comment}
bla
\myendcomment

\end{document}`
```

I get an error message like this:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> test.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me to read past where you wanted me to stop.
```

What does this error message mean and how do I get around the problem (without writing `\end{comment}` directly in the main text?

Comment: The `comment` environment is defined to gobble everything up to `\end{comment}`, without interpreting anything in between. Since it does no interpretation, `\myendcomment` is just the same as any other token, so it won't trigger the end of the comment: only `\end{comment}` would. So, short answer is: no, you can't. Maybe, if you tell more about your problem, some idea may pop up.

Comment: Thanks @egreg  What I want is this: a conditional compilation in which in case a) everything is written and in case b) only certain parts are written (the others are commented out by some means; what I want to avoid is manually putting \end{comment} in case b) 

I don't specifically need the comment environment, if there is another convenient way to hide text in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following two examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\newenvironment{mycomment}{}{}
%\excludecomment{mycomment}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{mycomment}
  Not commented text
\end{mycomment}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\newenvironment{mycomment}{}{}
\excludecomment{mycomment}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{mycomment}
  Commented text
\end{mycomment}
\end{document}
```